# Trouble with setting PBS Cluster using dask that finds my own modules

Tags: python, dask, distributed, dask-distributed, dask-jobqueue

I am running into some errors when trying to set up my own client using jobqueue PBS Cluster instead of using a default local cluster (i.e., `client = Client()`).

When setting the default, my own modules were recognized, but I realized my workers in the PBS Cluster could not find them. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295200/can-i-use-functions-imported-from-py-files-in-dask-distributed) and other research was helpful in understanding what I might be able to do.

I organized my modules into a package and used `pip install -e .` since I'll still be developing it. I confirmed my python environment site-packages directory has my package (via an .egg-link file).

I hoped installing the package would make my modules available, but I received the same error when I run my code after setting up a basic PBS Cluster:

```
cluster = PBSCluster(cores=x,memory=y)
cluster.scale(n)
client=Client(cluster)
```

Is my basic idea of installing the modules as a package not enough?

I looked into `client.upload_file` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118226/how-to-properly-use-dasks-upload-file-to-pass-local-code-to-workers) as another means to make the reference to my module file explicit. Will I need to do something like this still to install modules directly on the workers?

Apologies for length, I am very new to both dask and operating on a HPC.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, just a sanity check: When using an HPC cluster, there is typically a shared filesystem, which all workers can access (and so can your client machine).  Is that the case for your cluster?  If so, make sure your conda environment is in a shared location that all workers can access.

> I organized my modules into a package and used `pip install -e .`

That should work, as long as your source code is also on the shared filesystem.  The directory pointed to by the `.egg-link` file should be accessible from the worker machines. Is it?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The `egg-link` essentially contains `/projects/users/this_project/my_stuff` with the package contained in what in this example is called 'my_stuff'. This path also comes up with I `import sys` and check syspath.